# Chromatic number of Graph distribution

Tags: algorithm, graph-coloring

I am developing an algorithm for finding the chromatic number of a graph and providing a valid coloring using that number. For the purpose, I use a binary search for finding a possible answer K, and check whether K is possible using a genetic algorithm. The problem is that the chromatic numbers are distributed unevenly. For example for a graph with 1000 vertex, its chromatic number is most probably below 100. This way in my binary search, I need not to divide in the middle between the left boundary and the right boundary, but to find the middle of the chromatic number distribution. Do you know any resources from where I can get information about this distribution? I found a source giving me some details, but for graphs with less than 10 nodes: http://keithbriggs.info/cgt.html.

Comment: Even if this were on-topic (which it isn't -- it's a difficult maths question, not a programming question), you would have to specify the distribution of the input graph to get a meaningful answer.

Comment: So what I need is when I get a graph with n vertex, to know the probability it to be 1-chromatic, 2-chromatic, or something like this. Is this the distribution of the input graph you are looking for?

Comment: Not quite - see my answer below for a more detailed explanation of what input graph distribution Paul is referring to and what facts about chromatic number might be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a meaningful distribution of chromatic numbers on graphs of a certain size. In fact, to define such a distribution, you would first have to define a distribution on your input graphs. I'll describe what I mean. First, define a P_G to be a distribution on your input graphs. Then, consider the chromatic number as a random variable X that maps graphs to integers. Finally, you would obtain a distribution over X, call in P_X by P_X(X = k) = P_G( {G such that f(G) = k} ). I apologize for the messy formatting, let me know if this makes sense.

So I don't think that a distribution of chromatic numbers is what you want because (1) you may not have a distribution over your input graphs P_G and (2) it'd be hard to obtain a closed form for P_X even if you did have P_G. Even for the simple Erdos Renyi random graph model, the expected chromatic number is not known, let alone the distribution.

A few bounds that you might use are (1) the chromatic number is at most the maximum degree + 1, (2) the chromatic number is at least the size of the maximum clique. There are [several other bounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring#Lower_bounds_on_the_chromatic_number) you might look into, one being the Hoffman bound although obtaining this might be difficult since it requires computing eigenvalues. I think that your best bet might be a divide and conquer approach where you (1) decompose your graph into smaller possibly overlapping subgraphs and coloring those then (2) combine the colorings. I would imagine there are probably good hueristics that do this approximately, but I unfortunately don't have any references.